# Different StaticResource Style in iOS and Android

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, staticresource

I have a Entry with a Style from StaticRecourse , but is it possible to have 2 different Styles for iOS and Android

```
<Entry
                        x:Name="Partijladen"
                        Grid.Row="15"
                        Grid.Column="4"
                        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                        Keyboard="Numeric"
                        Style="{StaticResource AEntry}"
                        TextChanged="Partijladen_TextChanged" />
```

This is working but i want a different Style for Android lets say "BEntry". What do i change here of is it not possible

```
 Style="{StaticResource AEntry}"
```

And in App.xaml

```
<Style x:Key="AEntry" TargetType="Entry">
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#2c2c2e" />
        <Setter Property="WidthRequest" Value="80" />
        <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="10"  />
        <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalTextAlignment" Value="Center" />
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="BEntry" TargetType="Entry">
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="DarkGreen" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="25" />
        <Setter Property="WidthRequest" Value="80" />
        <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="10"  />
        <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalTextAlignment" Value="Center" />
    </Style>
```

Tryed this but error

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have two different syles:

```xml
<Entry
    ...
    Style="{x:OnPlatform Android={StaticResource AEntry},
                         iOS={StaticResource BEntry}}" />
```

---

Alternatively, you can set platform-specific style attributes in the same style.

```xml
<Style x:Key="AEntry" TargetType="Entry">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{x:OnPlatform UWP='', iOS='22', Android='20'}" />
    ...
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Shwa , when i try your example it is giving an error . After iOS Expected '}' Tryed al lot of options but no idea where to put it

Comment: Update the question with Style in App.xaml

Comment: @Bassies Sorry, missed a comma before "ios" (as typed here not copied), updated the answer.